# How to get intellisense for vuejs data binding in visual studio 2017?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I'm using vuejs in visual studio 2017, I have a data object representing a customer, it looks like this:

[image]

And it is displayed via text interpolation:

[image]

I’m wondering if there is any visual studio extension which can provide Intellisense for the text interpolation, ideally something which allows navigation to the definition and support for refactoring.

Comment: Hi stefan, what's your project type? Please have a look at this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.VuejsPack-18329

Comment: Hi Sara. My project type is ASP.NET MVC. I saw the extension it brings more intellisense but it provides no support for text interpolation.